# yii2-mongodb: How i can make the has many or has one relationship between two collection

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I am using the two collection which are State and City and want to relationship between both of them and using the below code for these:

**common\models\State.php**

```
return $this->hasMany(City::className(), ['state_id'=>'_id']);
```

**common\models\City.php**

```
return $this->hasOne(State::className(), ['_id' =>'state_id']);
```

When i run the below code, it is running and return blank result for cities.

```
$model = \common\models\State::find()->all();
```

When i change the `state_id` type in collection with `ObjectId` then it returns result. So please suggest me how can i typecast the `state_id` in relation.

Comment: The code uses the data type in the database. Are you sure that your saved data in using the right format in your database?

Comment: My City Document {
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f555c3ae67a2bd315202d3"),
    "state_id" : "54f44a940ca79e3233fc825d",
    "title" : "okhlama",
    "slug" : "okhlama",
    "code" : "12",
    "status" : "1",
    "created_at" : "1424853572",
    "updated_at" : 1425962524
}

Comment: My State Document {
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f44a940ca79e3233fc825d"),
    "title" : "Delhi",
    "slug" : "delhi",
    "code" : "123",
    "status" : "1",
    "created_at" : "1424853572",
    "updated_at" : 1425360052
}

Comment: Make state id save as an ObjectId and it will work

Comment: Yes, but how i can typecast it.  I did as $model->state_id = new \MongoId($postData['City']['state_id']); but not working

Comment: You can make a MongoIdValidator and add that your models rules to filter the value on save as a MongoId

Comment: can you give me example with code to do it.

Comment: I hate to self promote but I have such a validator in one of my extensions: https://github.com/Sammaye/mongoyii2/blob/master/validators/MongoIdValidator.php

Comment: i have already used  $model->state_id = new \MongoId($postData['City']['state_id']); It is not work. Please suggest how to type-cast.

Comment: try $_id = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id);

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

use `MongoBB` namespace.

**common\models\State.php**

```
return $this->hasMany(City::className(), [new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId(['state_id']) => '_id']);
```

**common\models\City.php**

```
return $this->hasOne(State::className(), ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId(['state_id'])]);
```

Answer (score -2):

For example; Comment are associated to a single user, in the comment class

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['_id' => 'user_id']);
}
```

In a controller where do you want to retrieve the comments and user objects

```
    $query = Comment::find()->orderBy('created_at DESC');
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'pagination' => ['pageSize' =>5],
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

You can access user objects with comments from another view like this

```
$model->user['profile_url']
```